# How to Access the Callable Task's input parameter inside thenAccept Method?

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice, completable-future, callable

I have the following methods to invoke some logic in a non-blocking way.

```
public void runParallelFunctions(Callable<Map<String, String>> invokerTask) {
    Supplier<Map<String, String>> taskSupplier = () -> {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
            return invokerTask.call();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return new HashMap<>();
    };
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(taskSupplier::get, executorService)
                         .thenAccept(this::printResultsFromParallelInvocations);
    }
    System.out.println("Doing other work....");
}

private void printResultsFromParallelInvocations(Map<String, String> result) {
        result.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ": " + value));
}
```

Below is the Callable I'm passing to the `runParallelFunctions` method above.

```
public Callable<Map<String, String>> createLambdaInvokerTask(final String payload) {
        return () -> invokeLambda(payload);
}
```

How can I access the `payload` parameter of `createLambdaInvokerTask` method in my `printResultsFromParallelInvocations` method? I need to concatenate the `payload` parameter to the `result` and print it. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: can't you change the definition to `public static Callable<java.util.Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>>> createLambdaInvokerTask(final String payload) {
  return () -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(payload, invokeLambda(payload));
 }` and of course the methods accordingly?

Comment: Why do you think that accessing that parameter at an entirely unrelated place should be possible at all? The method `printResultsFromParallelInvocations` receives the map returned by the `invokeLambda` method about which we don’t know anything. It could be implemented as `return Collections.emptyMap();`. In other words, there is no documented relationship between that map and the parameter. There’s not even a reason for `runParallelFunctions` to assume that the `Callable` argument has been created using the `createLambdaInvokerTask` method with a `payload` argument.

Comment: how come you post a different question, but do not reply to comments under this one?

Comment: @Eugene Apologies beforehand. I was trying to refactor the design of this logic according to the comment above from Holger and ran into another issue for which I posted the other question. I'm yet to process and figure where I should refactor, hence wanted to wait and ask a relevant follow up